# set UIButton's buttonType programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, programmatically-created

I have a `UIButton` which I've added in IB, however the view behind this button changes color and I need to switch the button's type between *InfoDark* and *InfoLight*. Bizarrely though, `buttonType` property is read only. So how can i switch between light and dark info buttons?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question is about changing the button type after it is instantiated. The referenced question is about how to instantiate the button in code. Please remove the duplication.

Comment: swift 5.2 : self.btnFont.buttonType = UIButton.ButtonType.system

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's no way to change the `.buttonType` once it's set.

You can prepare *two* buttons, and hide one of them depending on the background color.

Comment: well apparently theres a private setter method, by why something like that is private who knows. Thanks for you idea about 2 buttons, that's what I'll do.

Comment: @Jon: It's private because setting this will *not* convert a dark info button to a light one.

Answer (score 54):

You can't set buttonType readonly property, use below may help:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Comment: What's when you override UIButton class ? (I mean subclass)

Comment: In swift , If you are using custome class then, let button = MyCustomeClass.init(type: .custom)