# Change UIButton type in subclass if button created from storyboard

Tags: ios, uibutton

If I create a `UIButton` in Storyboard and assign its Class to be a subclass I made (`HighlightTappedButton`), is there a way in the subclass to change the `buttonType` to `Custom`?

I know I can just change the type to `Custom` in storyboard, but I don't want to have to remember to do that every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible at runtime. Since it is a read-only method. I think you will get helpful questions from these links.

[set UIButton's buttonType programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080011/set-uibuttons-buttontype-programmatically)

[Change UIButton type programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107338/change-uibutton-type-programatically)

[how to set UIButton type in UIButton Subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277863/how-to-set-uibutton-type-in-uibutton-subclass)

Comment: Yeah looks like it just isn't possible as far as I can tell.