# Subclassing UIButton with specific UIButtonType

Tags: xamarin.ios, uibutton

Is there a way to subclass `UIButton` with specifying its `UIButtonType`?

I want to use my button class in designer with type already set.

Comment: You could Subclass it and inside AwakeFromNib() method, you could set the Type for default. But as I know, correct me if I am wrong, there is no real way to use that Button in Designer, expect u see the default Button and set the class to it. But if u want to draw it by yourself and show that in Designer, there is no way

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you or not ?

Comment: `ButtonType` is read only property, so I dont think you can set it. About using in designer, I meant it like you create custom button class and then in designer assign that class to your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UIButtonType` is a read-only property, it is not possible to do this.

Only two scenario to subclass `UIButton` :

1. Create a subclass  of UIbutton and create a public method to wrap it's initial method.

   ```
   public class MyButton : UIButton
   {
       public static MyButton CreateButton()
       {
           return UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom) as MyButton;
       }
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   MyButton button = MyButton.CreateButton();
   ```

   **You can only use it in code not designer in this way**
2. Create a button from designer and rename its class 
   [image]

   It will auto generate a subclass of UIButton named CustomButton in you app folder ,and you can assign it to other buttons in designer.

   [image]

   But as i mentioned above, `UIButtonType` is a read-only property , no way to change it once it's set.

   ```
   public partial class CustomButton : UIButton
   {
       public CustomButton (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
       {
           this.ButtonType = UIButtonType.Custom;    //incorrect , read-only 

           this.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10);  //correct, read-write
       }
   }
   ```

   RE: [Change UIButton type in subclass if button created from storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521556/change-uibutton-type-in-subclass-if-button-created-from-storyboard)

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. Yeah, I have found out both possibilities too. I was only wondering, if there is maybe some other way. I want to use it the way you described in second answer, it's sad you cannot do it like that :/

Comment: @cole-xia-msft Hm, actually, can you elaborate more about casting in your first example? Because I'm getting `null` as result value and if I cast it as `(MyButton)UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom)`, I'm getting _Specified cast is not valid._ So I'm wondering, how this could worK for you?

Comment: @Naomak My mistake, i read the remark of `UIButton(UIButtonType type);` ,it says `you should avoid subclassing UIButton and then calling into this constructor from your subclass constructor.` so the first solution is also can't be working.